# How to have a C++ program solve for variables of an input value given the variables are limited integers?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have C++ solve the equation for an input value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120369/how-to-have-c-solve-the-equation-for-an-input-value)

I'm new to C++ and am just playing around...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int limbs(int handdmg, int armdmg, int chestdmg, int headshot, int legdmg)
{
    return handdmg + armdmg + chestdmg + legdmg + headshot;

}
main ()
{

    int totaldmg; 
    int handdmg; 
    int armdmg; 
    int chestdmg; 
    int legdmg;
    int headshot;
    int Dmgdial;
    int x;

    // limiting the variables to a smaller range of integers       

    handdmg = 0 < x < 5;
    armdmg = 10 < x < 15;
    chestdmg = 25 < x < 50;
    legdmg = 30 < x < 40;
    headshot = 80 < x < 120;

    cout  << "Enter your total damage taken:" << endl;
    cin >> totaldmg;

    Dmgdial = totaldmg;

    // want the variables to = the input value in the best smallest way possible

    limbs(handdmg, armdmg, chestdmg, headshot, legdmg) = Dmgdial;

    // then print the variables answers to the screen

    cout << "damage given to the hand:   " << handdmg << endl;
    cout << "damage given to the arm:    " << armdmg << endl;
    cout << "damage given to the chest:  " << chestdmg << endl;
    cout << "damage given to the leg:    " << legdmg << endl;
    cout << "damage given to the head:   " << headshot << endl;



    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(2505, '\n');
    cin.get();

    return 0;

}
```

So the concept is simple - you enter a value such as 156 into the program and then have the computer calculate the best way to get that value using the limited values of x.

However, `limbs(handdmg, armdmg, chestdmg, headshot, legdmg) = Dmgdial` doesn't work. It's backwards as far as the compiler is concerned.

How would I get this type of program to work?

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of `handdmg = 0 < x < 5;`?

Comment: sounds like you're trying to do Prolog, not C

Comment: @Mat not a possible, an exact duplicate. And asked by the same guy, too

Comment: Repeating your question isn't going to change the fundamentals of C++. You need to write the code that solves your equation (or find a library that does that). C++ isn't Mathematica or Matlab or whatever else people use for this type of thing.

Comment: sry.. i reposted before i got actual answers on the other post... No one understood it. so i reposted the exact code i was working with hoping it would be more understandable.. dont hate i understand now

Comment: @SeanHolt: You can just delete this question. It'll probably be closed as an exact dupe soon, anyway.

Comment: does it matter really? // I dont mean this in a snide way im curious.

Comment: You have to study the fundamentals of C++. However, C++ is not MATLAB, Mathematica, Maple or whatever else: you have to implement algorithms to solve linear systems of equations.

Answer (score 2):

> [..] the best way to get that value [...]

This is your task. "The computer" doesn't know anything about damage or what a headshot is. Take a paper and write down, how you want to calculate damage details from the total damage value. For example:

```
struct DamageDetails
{
   int head, leg, arm;
   const int HEAD_MAX = 120;
   const int HEAD_MIN = 80;

   static DamageDetails FromTotalDamage(int totalDamage)
   {
        DamageDetails damage;
        int damageTakenSoFar = totalDamage;
        damage.head = totalDamage / 2;  // 50% damage is taken to head
        if (damage.head > HEAD_MAX)
            damage.head = HEAD_MAX;
        damageTakenSoFar -= damage.head;
        // ...

        return damage;
   }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve 1 equation with 5 unknowns, which is an under-determined problem. You need a system of 5 equations with 5 unknowns to get a unique answer.

Moreover, you have not actually specified the equation - right now it just looks like you are assuming a linear equation t = x + y + z + v + w. That's probably not correct, considering the (strange) section you have that is limiting the variables.

Moreover, C++ is not a mathematical system for solving equations. You will need to write the code to solve them yourself, or use an third-party library.

Overall, I would say you are in over your head, as far as the math and the programming expertise needed to do what you are trying to do. You will benefit from learning more theory, before trying a task like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem using backtracking:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int v[100], n, int dmg;

void init(int k)
{
    v[k] = 0;
}

bool solutionReached( int k ) 
{
    if (k <= 5)
        return false;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        sum += v[i];
    }

    if(sum == dmg)
    {
        if( v[1] < 5 &&
            v[2] > 10 && v[2] < 15 &&
            v[3] > 25 && v[3] < 50 &&
            v[4] > 30 && v[4] < 40 &&
            v[5] > 80 && v[5] < 120)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void printSolution( int k ) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

bool hasSuccesor( int k ) 
{
    if(v[k] < 120 && k <= 5)
    {
        v[k]++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool isValid( int k ) 
{
    /*
    if(v[1] > 5)
        return false;
    if(!(v[2] > 10 && v[2] < 15))
        return false;
    if(!(v[3] > 25 && v[3] < 50))
        return false;
    if(!(v[4] > 30 && v[4] < 40))
        return false;
    if (!(v[5] > 80 && v[5] < 120))
        return false;
    */

    return true;
}

void bkt(int k)
{
    if(solutionReached(k))
        printSolution(k);
    else
    {
        init(k);
        while(hasSuccesor(k))
            if(isValid(k))
                bkt(k + 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    dmg = 200;
    n = 6;
    bkt(1);

    return 0;
}
```